# Set picture to Onsen UI Master-Details elements

Tags: javascript, cordova, onsen-ui

Hi i'm using Onsen UI Master-Details (Template) , but i have a doubt:
How i can set an image to every element ?

Follow the code:

```
 module.factory('$data', function() {
  var data = {};

  data.items = [
      {
          title: 'Item 1 Title',
          label: '4h',
          desc: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.'
      },
      {
          title: 'Another Item Title',
          label: '6h',
          desc: 'Ut enim ad minim veniam.'
      },
      {
          title: 'Yet Another Item Title',
          label: '1day ago',
          desc: 'Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.'
      },
      {
          title: 'Yet Another Item Title',
          label: '1day ago',
          desc: 'Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.'
      }
  ];

  return data;
```

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a way to do this!

```
data.items = [
      {
          Image: '1564940.jpg',
          title: 'Item 1 Title',
          label: '4h',
          desc: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.'
      },
```

And :

```
<div ><img class="item-thum" ng-src="images/{{item.Image}}" style="margin:auto;"></div>
```